# What happens if Exporess.js app never ends req?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Suppose I wrote an Exporess app and it never calls any methods on `res`. If I make a request then it will hang. What happens when a hanging request is made? Will some resources be taken and not released forever? If so then which and how much? Memory? Handles? Zombie processes?

Comment: Yes, this can lead to what's known as [Denial of Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack aka DoS if enough are requested in a short space of time, although requests will have a default timeout period. And yes, you should most definitely try to protect against it.

Comment: Eventually the request will timeout.  See your options on setting the time here: [Node.js: What is the difference between server.setTimeout, server.timeout and server.keepAliveTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51935860/691711).  That's not  to say that you shouldn't take steps to keep from letting the server overload.

Comment: @James He means what if the `res.send()` is never called in node js ,only the request from client is send .The DOS attack is out of the picture here.

Comment: @Shubh I was originally going to say that this isn't exactly a DoS attack since it would be the OP's own fault, but there have been plenty of services that have been accidentally set up in such a way that normal use actually causes DoS through no fault of the actual users.  You could basically duck-type certain bugs as DoS.

Comment: @Shubh so you don't think if the server gets flooded with hanging requests it won't eventually starve the HTTP sockets and/or even exhaust available memory? That's the exact definition of a DoS attack...

Comment: Yes that could be a possible scenario ,kind of DOS but not actual hackers trying to malform your server with unwanted requests.

Comment: Could you focus your question?  I'm not exactly sure how to answer it as written right now.  I suppose my first comment would count as an answer, but I think you might be asking **how** to defend against something like this which may be too broad for SO but might be more on topic for Server Fault or some other exchange.

Comment: @Shubh ok, I see what you mean.... I didn't mean this would be someone _intentially_ doing this, I simply mean it would be the _equivalent_ of that type of attack. I should've made that clearer in my original comment.

Comment: @zero298 OK, if you say what exactly you don't like about my question then I can fix it. I made it more clear, I hope. In general I am interested in consequences, not what to do.